# Highcharts not displaying

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/dws18w18/

```js
$('#reg-chart').highcharts({
  title: {
    text: 'Daily Average Registration',
    x: -20
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["2017 JUL 01","2017 JUL 02","2017 JUL 03"]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Users',
    data: ["20","1","61"]
  }]
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="reg-chart"></div>
```

what's wrong with this snippet? Why it's not showing anything? Also, exact same issue on my production site, works fine on my local server. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data must be numbers not strings

```
series: [{
    name: 'Users',
    data: ["20","1","61"] // Don't work
}]    
series: [{
    name: 'Users',
    data: [20,1,61] //Works
}]
```

[Link to updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/dws18w18/1/)